# How to add CSP nonce for emotion generated styles in storybook webpack config?

Tags: webpack, content-security-policy, storybook, emotion, css-in-js

We're adding `style src 'self'` to the HTML page and emotion is generating styles dynamically to the header like below

```
<head>
    <style data-emotion>
        ...
    </style>
    <style data-emotion>
        ...
    </style>
    <style data-emotion>
        ...
    </style>
    <style data-emotion>
        ...
    </style>
    ...
</head>
```

How to generate nonce for above styles with the below such storybook webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack

Generally for generating nonce in webpack we do like - https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/559

Emotion has the below link which tells that we can add nonce using `CacheProvider`, but not very clear how to implement the same - https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/cache#nonce

It will be helpful if anyone can tell hints regarding setting nonce in storybook webpack config for emotion styles